# Passing Non-Static Member Function as argument

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers, binary-search-tree, non-static

**SalesMap.h excerpt-**

```
typedef BST<Sales> BinarySearchTree;//type defined for Sales_Map construction
typedef map<Date, BinarySearchTree> sales_map;//type defined for map construction
sales_map Sales_Map;
```

**SalesMap.cpp excerpt-**

Highest and SetHigh are both public

```
void SalesMap::Highest(){
    void (SalesMap::*SetHighPTR)(Sales);//create non-static function pointer
    SetHighPTR = &SalesMap::SetHigh; //assign address of function void SetHigh(Sales sales)
    //it is an iterator to a specific element in Sales_Map
    it->second.InSearch(&SetHighPTR); // pass SetHigh into BST object function InSearch
}

void SalesMap::SetHigh(Sales sales)//test input sales object against global highprice variable
{
    double price = sales.GetPrice();
    if(price < high)
        high = price;
}
```

**BST.h**

```
Public:
     void InSearch(void (*f)(T) );//calls recursive InSearch function
Private:
      void InSearch(node*& leaf, void (*f)(T) );

template <class T>//public InSearch
void BST<T>::InSearch( void (*f)(T) )
{
    InSearch(root, (*f));
}

template <class T>//Private InSearch
void BST<T>::InSearch(node*& leaf, void (*f)(T))
{
    if(leaf != NULL)
    {
        InSearch(leaf->left);
        (*f)(key);
        InSearch(leaf->right);
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a callback function in BST.h.
I keep getting the error below:

```
error C2664: 'void BST<T>::InSearch(void (__cdecl *)(T))' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__thiscall SalesMap::* )(Sales)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(T)'
```

I am unsure of the right syntax needed for this problem and cannot figure out what I should do and where.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I suggest you re-edit your question and post a small reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: *function pointer* are different than *method pointer*.

Comment: [`boost.bind`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html) solves this problem

Comment: [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) is also of interest here.

Answer (score 3):

The problem basically is your trying to convert a **member function pointer** into a **function pointer**, this is per definition simply not possible in C++, because a member function pointer always needs an object on which its getting called. (`this` needs to point somewhere)

Static methods of classes don't need any object and therefore are function pointers as well.

If you want to use member function pointers your `InSearch` method should have the following Parameters:

```
template <class T>//public InSearch
void BST<T>::InSearch( void (SalesMap::*f)(T) )
```

then you need an object which is of type `SalesMap` or any derived class to call this method:

```cpp
//Using an object pointer
(mySalesObjectPtr->*f)(key);
//No pointer
(mySalesObject.*f)(key);
```

Of course you can create an overload for function pointers, as you've already done, which is then suitable for global functions and static methods.

The beginning of [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible) gives a good overview over those two types of function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example when you want to pass a function pointer of a member function from outside that member class.

```
class A
{
private:
    void(A::*m_myFuncPointer)(); ///declaring a private member function pointer

public:
    void init( void(A::*someFunc)() ){
        m_myFuncPointer = someFunc;    ///stores the function pointer
        (this->*m_myFuncPointer)();    ///calls the function using member function
    }  
    void execute(){
        std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;
    }
 };

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.init(&A::execute);
}
```